# Cost calculation of Azure Log analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there any way to get the details how the cost of Azure Log analytics service is metered? How do I know why my analytics log service is so expensive? Do you have any tips? I just wish log the applications of azure functions paying as little as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Log Analytics is priced by ingestion (GB/day), and retention after the first month.

Ingestion is priced at $2.30/GB/day, so if you collect 1GB of logs daily, your monthly cost would be $57.50.

Retention is priced at $0.10/GB/month after the first month, so if you want to retain for 6 months, and you ingest at 1GB/day, it's 30GB * $.10 in month 2, plus 60 GB * $.10 = $6 in month 3, plus 90 GB * $.10 in month 4 = $9, plus 120 GB * $.10 in month 5 = $12.

This does not cover alerts, which are billed separately, application insights, which has its own ingestion pricing model, or notifications.

You can calculate pricing for your own projected scenario by searching for "Azure Monitor" at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator

Answer (score 2):

I would start by understanding the [pricing model of Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cost-logs). TL;DR, Log Analytics is priced by ingestion (GB/Day) and retention period, also, it offers a reserved capacity tiers.

To understand how you can optimize your cost, there is a great [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/best-practices-cost), there are great information on how to understand what contribute to your bill and what can be done to reduce it.

I would also suggest to check the workspace **insights** blade, under the **Usage** tab you will find useful information on what are the top resources contributing for high data ingestion.

Comment: The Insights blade seems to be the right direction to an answer for the OP but for some reason I'm unable to view anything under the Usage tab. It's as if it's loading but nothing ever shows. Not sure if others are experiencing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have added to Azure Monitor new options to support cheaper logs ingestion and archiving. See announcement here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability-blog/the-next-evolution-of-azure-monitor-logs/ba-p/3143195

Docs for Basic Logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-workspace-overview#log-data-plans-preview

Docs for Archive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-retention-archive

Let me know if you have more questions,
Meir, PM, Azure Monitor Logs